# fingers for KeyTapGesture in leap motion

Tags: gesture, leap-motion, keytab

I want to make an application for typing character which corresponding with specific finger. I have tried with finger.isExtended to sense which finger is "stroke" or bend, but the movement of the fingers should be maximum to be detected using this function.

I would try another function using KeyTapGesture, but I do not know whether this function can be differentiate the finger or known which finger do the tap.

does anyone know how to determine the particular fingers do the tap?

I have add the pointable() and here is my  C# code:

```
case Gesture.GestureType.TYPE_KEY_TAP:
        KeyTapGesture keytap = new KeyTapGesture (gesture);
        controller.Config.SetFloat("Gesture.KeyTap.MinDownVelocity", 40.0f);
        controller.Config.SetFloat("Gesture.KeyTap.HistorySeconds", .2f);
        controller.Config.SetFloat("Gesture.KeyTap.MinDistance", 1.0f);
        controller.Config.Save();
        HandList handsForGesture = gesture.Hands;
        Hand rightHand = handsForGesture[0];
        Pointable tappingPointable = keytap.Pointable;
        PointableList pointablesForGesture = rightHand.Pointables;

        int exFingers = 0;
        for (int f = 0; f < rightHand.Pointables.Count; f++)
            {
              Pointable digit = rightHand.Pointables[f];
              if (digit.IsValid)
                {
                    exFingers++;
                    SafeWriteLine("Finger: " + f);
                  }
              }
    break;
```

And the result is all the fingers do the tap even though I did only with one finger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KeyTap gesture object has a [pointable()](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/cpp/api/Leap.KeyTapGesture.html#cppclass_leap_1_1_key_tap_gesture_1a249c63ba650070ad9bbfec7fc497443a) attribute for this purpose. (Use [pointableIds](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/api/Leap.KeyTapGesture.html#pointableIds) in JavaScript.)

Comment: Thank you  @Charles Ward, I edit my question to add the code, this code resulting all the finger do the tap even though I did it using one finger.

Comment: keytap.Pointable should be the tapping finger. rightHand.Pointables will always be every finger on that hand. Also note that you should set config values earlier. Setting them as above won't have effect until the next frame (and there is no need to set them more than once).